# how to implement interface with abstract members that accept option word?

Tags: f#, fable-f#

the interface code as follows

```ml
type [<AllowNullLiteral>] QueryInfo =
            abstract status: QueryInfoStatus option with get, set
            abstract lastFocusedWindow: bool option with get, set
            abstract windowId: float option with get, set
            abstract windowType: QueryInfoWindowType option with get, set
            abstract active: bool option with get, set
            abstract index: float option with get, set
            abstract title: string option with get, set
            abstract url: U2<string, ResizeArray<string>> option with get, set            abstract currentWindow: bool option with get, set
            abstract highlighted: bool option with get, set
            abstract discarded: bool option with get, set
            abstract autoDiscardable: bool option with get, set
            abstract pinned: bool option with get, set
            abstract audible: bool option with get, set
            abstract muted: bool option with get, set
            abstract groupId: float option with get, set
```

I want to pass a parameter to the function that accept argument type `QueryInfo`

```
abstract query: queryInfo: QueryInfo -> unit
```

so how do I use the interface to pass a value`active=true,currentWindow=true` that satisfies the interface?

in fact I tried the code, but failed.

```ml
type Query(active:bool option,currentWindow:bool option) =
    interface Chrome.Tabs.QueryInfo with
        member _.active = active
        member _.currentWindow = currentWindow

query(Query(true,true))
```

the IDE told me that

`This expression was expected to have type 'bool option' but here has type 'bool'`

if I add some type, I get this:

[image]

Comment: I'm not certain I understand your question, but try this: `query(Query(Some true, Some true))`

Comment: The second error message is telling you that if you want to implement the `QueryInfo` interface, you must provide an implementation of all those members. At a minimum, you can override each one such that your implementation throws an exception.

Comment: @BrianBerns Is there any way I can implement only the part of the interface that I want?

Comment: No, because any method of the interface might be called. But you can [stub out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_stub) most of the methods so they don’t do anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is a question about interop with JavaScript libraries from Fable. This means that you are compiling to JavaScript and can use extra tricks that Fable provides for accessing JavaScript libraries. The tricks are documented in the [Fable JS interop documentation](https://fable.io/docs/communicate/js-from-fable.html#plain-old-javascript-objects) and there are a few options listed there.

In your case, it seems that a nice thing to do would be to use the `!!` oeprator. This is a Fable-specific trick (that the Fable compiler understands) that lets you create interface values like this. I think the following should do the trick:

```
let x: Chrome.Tabs.QueryInfo = !!{| active=Some true; currentWindow=Some true |}
Chrome.Tabs.query(x)
```

In fact, you may be even able to call the `query` function directly:

```
Chrome.Tabs.query(!!{| active=Some true; currentWindow=Some true |})
```

I have not actually tried compiling and running this, but based on your example and the Fable docs, something along those lines should work.